# UI based application using event-based async pattern

Tags: c#

I have implemented a component according to the event-based asynchronous pattern from Microsoft to interact with a REST-Service which I want to use inside a UI-based application.

I would post the code, but there is quite a lot.

Anyway, what i observe in short is:

1. I start my application, which runs on ThreadID 1, so the UI belongs to ThreadID 1
2. I register a method to the component which updates my UI when the taskCompleted event fires (still running on ThreadID 1)
3. I call the runTaskAsync method which creates an AsyncOperation using the AsyncOperationManager, as described in the article, and call its BeginInvoke method.
4. After calling BeginInvoke, the execution switches from ThreadID 1 to ThreadID 5 (or any) and enters the working-method
5. After work is done by ThreadID 5, the AsyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted method is called and execution swithes to another ThreadID 7 (or any) instead of returning to ThreadID 1.

The Problem is that the UI-update method is executed by the third Thread (ID 7) which does not own the UI.

In my workaround, I check for the this.InvokeRequired Property:

```
private void task_completed(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action<EventArgs>(login_completed), new[] { e });
    }
    else
    {
        //Execute UI stuff             
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if I made a mistake, or if this behavior is normal.

I expect the AsyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted method to invoke ThreadID 1 directly. Instead it creates another thread which has to invoke thread 1...

It would be nice if it invoked thread 1 directly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "It works fine but i wondering if i made a mistake or if this behaveor is normal." what behavior?  You just said it works fine.

Comment: EDIT: I expect the AsyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted to invoke thread 1 to execute my ui. instead it creates another thread and i have to invoke thread 1 manualy in this additional thread

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, AsyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted() is calling Post, which ends up doing this (according to Reflector, using .NET 4.5):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(d.Invoke), state);
```

Where d is your callback delegate.

So your delegate is being run on a thread from the thread pool.

What you're seeing is normal.

Comment: Just FYI - [the actual source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/AsyncOperation.cs,87d5517c1aa81b46,references) is available too

Comment: Thanks for posting the link, James.